# Maven Dependencies []

Tags: maven-plugin

I am building Jenkins Maven Job. When I run Jenkins Job,I am getting following Dependencies error.

```
Failed to execute goal on project rabbitmq-build-trigger: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:rabbitmq-build-trigger:hpi:2.3.4: Failed to collect dependencies at **org.jenkins-ci.plugins:xunit:jar:1.90 -> org.jenkins-ci.lib.dtkit:dtkit-metrics-model:jar:2.0.0:** Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jenkins-ci.lib.dtkit:dtkit-metrics-model:jar:2.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci:jenkins:pom:1.34 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): Connect to repo.jenkins-ci.org:80 [repo.jenkins-ci.org/*.*.*.*, repo.jenkins-ci.org/*.*.*.*, repo.jenkins-ci.org/*.*.*.*] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

I have uploaded all required dependencies into our employer specific remote repo. and employer do not want to download any artifact from Central repo. Hence, accessing or calling external URL from slave box is restricted.

I do not know how dependencies work through a POM file. From the above message, "->" is travelling along with dependencies file

Can someone explain me what is wrong and how I supposed to resolve this issue? You answer is really matters to me

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you successfully uploaded specifically 'org.jenkins-ci:jenkins:pom:1.34' to the remote repository? 
Also, ensure the remote repository is added as a repository element in your project's pom, like so:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

(more information on repositories here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

You might see if you can retrieve the artifacts by using each one's URL in a browser. If so, there's something amiss with your maven project repo configuration.